# Do I need my own server if I move my Elastic Beanstalk app to use Docker?

Tags: django, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a working Elastic Beanstalk, Django app, but for several reasons, I will like to move from using the preconfigured Python platform, to using a Generic Docker platform.

There is very little documentation or examples for using a real app using Docker within EB, so I am not clear on whether once I move to Docker, I need to manage the server as well, meaning that my docker image will need its own Apache/nginx server on top of my django setup, or if EB will still have its apache server side by side with the docker image on the EC2 instance. In other words, is the final CMD on my docker image a simple 'python manage.py runserver" type cmd? or some 'supervisord -n'? Do I need an image similar to https://github.com/dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you posted is a great place to start, and is a pretty good sketch of what a functional EB/Docker/Django setup looks like. Also take a look at https://github.com/AndrewSmiley/django-docker-eb (which uses gunicorn instead of nginx/uwsgi). You will in fact need some sort of server running in your Docker container--this server (nginx in the example you linked to) is what lets your Docker container talk to the EC2 instance that's running it.

If you look at a typical Dockerfile, at some point you're using `EXPOSE` to make a port visible to the outside world. ElasticBeanstalk will communicate with your container on this port, so your container needs its own internal server of some kind to interact with those requests. ElasticBeanstalk will install its own outer server on the EC2 instance (nginx I believe) which funnels traffic to your container. In other words: Net <-> EC2 Instance <-> EB webserver <-> Docker <-> Server in your container <-> Your application

While you could conceivably run `python manage.py runserver` as your Docker `CMD`, the webserver that it sets up isn't well suited for production. That's why the image you linked to uses supervisord to run a more production-ready webserver configuration. In both cases, though, you're running a server inside your Docker container!

Answer (score 0):

No. Elastic Beanstalk will effectively be your "server" if it contains all application, database and other services you need. It will still be running EC2 instances but you will not need to manage them directly.